# Crystal Reports formatting a Cross-tab with multiple fields down

Tags: oracle11g, crystal-reports

I am querying data in a table that has a field value that I want across the top of my report, and then multiple values I want to display down.  Perhaps a cross-tab will work, but if so, how?  (I'm open to suggestions to using something besides a cross-tab or formatting the original data differently.)

My data looks something like this:

```
Record Type   Value1   Value2   PercentV1V2  Value3  PercentV1V3
 TypeA          10        100       10          50       20
 TypeB          20        40        50         200       10  
 TypeC          50        100       50          50      100
```

And, I would like my output to look like this (this formatting is not so negotiable)

```
                  TypeA       TypeB         TypeC
  Set1Info
    Value1          10           20           50
    Value2         100           40          100
    PercentV1V2     10           50           50
  Set2Info
    Value3          50          200           50
    PercentV1V3     20           10          100
```

I've been messing with a cross-tab and I can get the first value set.  But there doesn't appear to be a way to add a new row to the cross-tab.

I think I could format the data differently and use a cross-tab, but I'd prefer doing the calculations in my procedure, not in Crystal, if possible.  They won't be simple totals, in any case.

```
So, if I formatted my data like so:
    Record Type   ValueType   Value   
     TypeA         Value1       10
     TypeA         Value2      100 
     TypeA         PercentV1V2  10   <-- this would take another pass to calculate
     TypeB         Value1       20
```

etc, then I think the cross-tab would work better.  But even then, would I be able to make formatting changes between Set1Info and Set2Info?

Or, is there a way with the original data to get the Types across the top and the values down, but without using a cross-tab?  I can hard-code the headers, but that means every number displayed would have to be a formula, right?  (I'd need to match up the correct number with each RecordType and ValueType.)

It seems like I'm overlooking something obvious, an easy way to approach this.  But sometimes with Crystal, there is no easy way.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I understand your problem and requirement... looks like what you have done is correct.

Only one addition that comes in to my mind to solve the issue is to use `Embeeded Summay`.

Use the embeeded summary and add a blank row where require and add your `Set2Info` as header.

Solution 2:

One option you can try is to create a formula `@Group` and manually saperate the rows and create a group.

```
if RecordType = "Value1" or    RecordType = "Value2" or RecordType = "  PercentV1V2"
then "Set1info"
```

go to the cross tab expert and place the formula first in rows part so that it will group as required and show you a header.